# tcp client can't connect to local server randomly in unity

Tags: c#, tcp, unity-game-engine, client

I have an unity3d client using `BeginConnect` to connect my local server, but the connection can not be established **randomly**, espacially after I restart the unity editor. Once it connected, it will become quite normal even I restart the game(not the editor) many times.

The wireshark shows that nothing are sent when issue occures.

I have another very similar client but it can connect to my another similar local server very perfectly.

Any idea what caused the problem?

Thanks in advance.

===

PS.

1. Even with a retry mechanism the client can connect to server succssfully but the later async operations(`BeginSend` & `BeginReceive`) may still randomly stop working.
2. The connect may be unresponsive even I ran the client without runing the server.
3. I have code to close the socket in the `OnApplicationQuit()` function:

   ```
   socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
   socket.Close();
   ```
4. Another similar client has almost the same codebase but works very well.
5. I found another similar issue: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/925955/socketbeginwrite-no-response-in-463f1.html?sort=oldest. but it can't explain why my another client(same version of unity) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/925955/socketbeginwrite-no-response-in-463f1.html?sort=oldest, it seems that in unity3d v4.6.3f1, the mono runtime has some bugs in the implementation of BeginXXX series functions.

The unity team may fixed these bugs in newer version(not tested), but I still need to stay on v4.6.3f1, so the workaround is **replacing the BeginXXX with XXXAsync series**. (tested and works for my problem)

Answer (score 0):

Most of our TCP related problems were related to failing to close the listener thread or failing to disconnect from server.

When you create a thread in editor environment, the thread will continue to exist as long as the editor runs, even if you stop the game. If you use TCP in a multithreaded way, you have to manually stop the thread in some OnDestroy or OnDisable methods.

Also make sure you disconnect from server when you stop the game.

If these were not enough to solve your problem, then I may be able to help if you can share some example code that causes this problem.

Comment: It should work as long as you carefully handle the Unity editor specific things I mentioned above. Maybe your code has a bug or something. Did you try to build and run?

Comment: I use the socket.BeginConnect with an AsyncCallback to handle the result. The callback was never be called even after a very long time. It also got no response even when I ran the client without running my local server. From the MSDN, the runtime will use a background thread to handle the request, so is it possible that the request was droped by the runtime?